# What is the size of European SMEs in case of money flow and revenue?

Tags: statistics, euro-area

I want to focus my product on SMEs (B2B financial service). So to research the market size I decided to check the numbers first. I had not a very productive time studding EU statistic data on [their official site](http://ec.europa.eu/growth/smes/business-friendly-environment/sme-definition_en). 
I thought that it's possible to determine market size of SMEs by their total revenue or operational balance (money flow). If you have better metrics please feel free to advice.
Is there someone who know where can I get these numbers from?

Comment: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/structural-business-statistics/structural-business-statistics/sme has turnover figures by size of employment and industry and country

Comment: @Henry I open http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/submitViewTableAction.do from the page you linked. Could you please say what these numbers stand for?

Comment: The first number in the top left of your linked table of 543.4 seems to represent the turnover of businesses in 2006 in Belgium in the mining and quarrying sector with between 50 and 249 employees being a total of 543.4 million euros that year.  Changing the indicator to "Enterprises - number" seems to give a corresponding figure of 12, so presumably their average turnover was about 45 million euros.